# Conditional update in Salesforce API

Tags: synchronization, salesforce

Is it possible to make the update method fail if e.g. the modification date is different than X in Salesforce API?

The task is to update a field of an object in Sfdc only if the record hasn't changed since I last got it from Sfdc.

Even if I query an object in Sfdc and check if it has been modified and it hasn't and then I issue an update there is still a window where the record could change between my check and the update command. This is an old concurrency sync problem - Does Sfdc has any mechanisms to help dealing with it?

Thanks in advance,

Tymek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend looking at the [Salesforce Order of Execution](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) before deciding on a solution.

You could try a Validation Rule (with the ISCHANGED function) to check whether a field has changed or a Trigger (on Update using trigger.new and trigger.old to compare values).

Check out [this document on Validation Rules](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/fields_validation_considerations.htm) and [this document for Triggers](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_CSH.htm#apex_triggers_defining.htm) for additional reference.

Comment: Is is possible to 'fail' an Web API update from a trigger? If so can you specify an error code/message?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. The addError() method is mentioned here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_exceptions.htm. You may want to look at this one too: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not have a trigger on update of the object? I believe it should be called even when the API is run and you can check whether or not there was an update prior to yours?